# .NET MVC redirect from Handler and sameSite=strict cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, httphandler, samesite

I have a big problem. I am using handler to handle saml response. In handler I am checking if everything is ok and then I am loging in user with cookie.

```
context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

after this I am redirecting:

```
context.Response.Redirect("~/", false);
```

After redirect user is not logged in (I have to refresh page and he is logged in) because cookies are not sent. The are set with **SameSite=Strict.**

Also in global.asax I am checking if user has active session with actual browser and it is not working because no **sessionID == no cookies => Logoff user**.
Flow is like this:

```
Go to login page -> redirect to saml system -> redirect to handler -> redirect to Home
```

How can I redirect user with all the cookies between pages on my website with SameSite set to Strict?

Comment: SameSite restrictions only apply when the user is crossing origins/domains (either redirections or CORS). Your post doesn’t say if users are coming from, or going to, other sites. Please clarify this.

Comment: I added a flow to my question. Probably problem is the on "redirect to handler" (no cookies sent)

Comment: The redirect-from-SAML-provider step is causing the break because Strict-mode SameSite cookies are not sent in redirections. The only fix is to change *your* cookie to Lax (if using GET redirections) or None (if using POST redirections).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change SameSite=Strict to SameSite=Lax. It is safe still and it's working